# Reading a Stream is changing the hash value of it

Tags: c#, hash, stream

I have the following code, which is reading a Stream to store the content of it as a string. Unfortunately after the StreamReader is not used anymore, the hash value of the Stream has changed. How is this possible? The Stream is readonly and thus can't be changed.

```
string content;
string hash = Cryptography.CalculateSHA1Hash(stream); // 5B006E35CF1838871FDC1E3DF52B0CB5A8A97274
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
   content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
hash = Cryptography.CalculateSHA1Hash(stream); // DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709
```

Comment: Please don't add "- C#" to your titles. That's what we use tags for on [so].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SHA1 value `DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709` is the result of hashing an empty string. The call to `Cryptography.CalculateSHA1Hash` reads everything (from the current position to the end) from the string and hashes it. There's no more data to read after the first call to `Cryptography.CalculateSHA1Hash`.

I would also guess that your `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` returns an empty string due to the same reason.

Comment: ReadToEnd doesn't return an empty string. But with the help of your hint and the fact that the stream is closed after using (what I should have known) it's clear now that calculating the hash of a closed stream returns a different one. :)

Answer (score 2):

Are the 2 values always the same? It's possible that your method is creating a hash from the contents of the stream, and in the second instance the stream is at the end position so has no more data to be read.

If you seek the stream back to the beginning do you get consistent numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the stream `Position` has changed (e.g. by `ReadToEnd`) and the digest is computed from the current `Position` ?

It's only a guess since we can't help you *much* without seeing the code for `Cryptography.CalculateSHA1Hash`.

Answer (score 1):

You have placed your `StreamReader` into a `using` block - a good thing. However, `TextReader.Dispose` by default calls `Dispose` on the underlying stream. This is likely to change things.

Try checking the hash from within the `using` block.